# PHP - which are fastest and best way to get html content

Tags: php, html, fopen, fgets

I have to read an URL html content about ~1 MB, exactly is 926 KB.
And I already create 2 functions.

An URL content with filesize ~1 MB:

```
https://example.com/html_1MB_Content.html
```

And here are 2 functions that I was created:

```
function getContent1 ($url) {
    $file_handle = fopen($url, "r");
    while (!feof($file_handle)) {
       $line = fgets($file_handle);
            echo $line;
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
}

function getContent2 ($url) {
    $handle = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($handle, array(
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '', 
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1
    ));
    $curl_response = curl_exec($handle);
    curl_close($handle);
    return $curl_response;
}

$testUrl = 'https://example.com/html_1MB_Content.html';

$result1 = getContent1 ($testUrl);

$result2 = getContent2 ($testUrl);
```

What I want is **fastest** and **less memory**. Which is best in this case?

One more question is anyway to read page content from bottom to top, if found data stop reading?

Comment: One function outputs the content by using echo, the other returns the content.  Apples and oranges.

Comment: *Which is best in this case?* - measure and tell us

Comment: Yep, you might confused that, usually I'm using the curl function, I just found getContent1() on Internet, then asking this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to know how long it takes to execute your code, you may use these couple of code..

```
//put this to the start of your code..
$time_start = microtime(true); 

//here goes your code...

//and put this to the end of your code...
echo 'Total execution time in seconds: ' . (microtime(true) - $time_start).'. memory used in kb : '.echo memory_get_usage();
```

this will show you performance time in second and size of used memory in KB...